# Read txt files and separate by the chr

Tags: r

I have a question on reading large txt files and separate it based on the character "TIME".
Each "TIME" represents the pressure of a spatial area at a particular point in time.
How should I write the readtext functions that recognize the "TIME" characters and split them ?

[image: A large txt files separated by characters]

Comment: Can you please use dput to show the example

Comment: Hello Akrun, here is the output from dput function. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYSjA.png

Comment: Sorry, from images can't copy.  Can you post the output on github if it is large or edit your post and copy/paste the output of dput

Comment: Hello Akrun! Here is the link: https://github.com/yuchenxiao95/Pore-Pressure-datasets The Example.txt is the example file I am using, the actualt file has many more dates, and the Output of dput.txt is the output of the dput function copied to a .txt file. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first create a folder so that I can save the new files in it. Also, I would put the original data file in this folder.

```
# setwd("....")     # Set the working directory as the folder you just created.
```

I saved the data structure that you provided in "data.txt"

The following lines will split your data (which is in "data.txt" in my computer) into files that have consecutive names, such as "data1.txt", "data2.txt", and so on.

```
incon = file("data.txt", "r")
i = 0
while (TRUE) {
    line = readLines(incon, n = 1)
    if (length(line) == 0) {
        break
    }
    if (regexpr("TIME:", line) > 0) {
        if (exists("outcon")) close(outcon)
        i = i + 1
        outcon = file(paste("data", i, sep=""), "w")
        writeLines(line, outcon)
    } else {
        writeLines(line, outcon)
    }
}
close(outcon)
```